# Documentation of internal helper function using `roxygen2`

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am new to creating my own packages and I am using `roxygen2`.

I am creating a package with a lot of internal helper functions and I was wondering if I have to document all of them.  I understand the importance of documentation but some functions are fairly simple and are just wrapper around other functions for convenience. I have done a basic search of the web but I don't seem to be able to find a definitive answer.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the functions exposed outside the package?

Comment: formatted roxygen comments are necessary if the function should have human readable documentation. In general comments are necessary to understand, use and maintain the functions in the package.

Comment: @anotherfred I am using the keyword internal to prevent from being exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "have to".  One interpretation is, "Do I have to document these functions to pass checks?"  The answer to that question is no.  As long as the function isn't exported from the package, `R CMD check` won't require that you document it.

Another interpretation is "Do I have to document it to help myself in maintaining this package?"  That question is harder to answer.  Some functions are so obvious that they don't really need any documentation beyond their name, e.g. a `print` method with no extra arguments beyond those of the generic.

Other functions aren't so obvious, or have arguments whose meaning isn't obvious.  It's a good idea to document those if you plan to maintain your package for a long time, because you might forget the details between now and whenever a problem arises.  And if you are releasing your package to others, you should plan on long term maintenance, because if it is useful, people will use it.